# Sort according to alphabetical order with respect to count

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary, count

```
from collections import *
def compress(s):
    res = Counter(s)

    for key,value in res.items():
        print(key, value)

compress("hhgoogle")
```

Output:

```
h 2
g 2
o 2
l 1
e 1
```

How to sort it in alphabetical order  with respect to count, i.e.:

Required output:

```
g 2
h 2
o 2
e 1
l 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.. [Sorting Howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort it alphabetically, then sort the occurrences. 
The join is merely to output it in the format you have described.

```
from collections import *
def compress(s):
    res= Counter(s)
    alphabetic_res = sorted(res.most_common(), key=lambda tup: tup[0])
    final_res = sorted(alphabetic_res, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
    print("\n".join("%s,%s" % tup for tup in final_res))

compress("hhgoogle")

OUT: g,2
     h,2
     o,2
     e,1
     l,1
```

Comment: You are welcome, if one of the responses answered your question you can mark it as resolved with the gray checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
from collections import *

print(sorted(Counter('hhgoogle').items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))
# [('g', 2), ('h', 2), ('o', 2), ('e', 1), ('l', 1)]
```

[demo](https://trinket.io/python3/4adaa0ab86)

Comment: Nice use of negated value to effect a single sort!  (+1)  But why `most_common()` instead of simply `items()` if you're doing a full sort anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
from collections import *
def compress(s):
    res= Counter(s)
    l1 = sorted(res.most_common(), key=lambda t: t[0])
    l2 = sorted(l1, key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
    print('\n'.join([f"{t[0]} {t[1]}" for t in l2]))
compress("hhgoogle")
```

Output:

```
g 2
h 2
o 2
e 1
l 1
```